Avalonia UI применение стиля
Не применяется стиль для TextBox
При попытке применить стиль ничего не меняется, подскажите пожалуйста как это испаравить.
Ниже представлен код на .axaml
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="Messenger.MainWindow"
        Title="Messenger"
        Background="White">
 
    <StackPanel Margin="10"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="Регистрация"
                   FontSize="20"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="0,0,0,20"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Foreground="Black"/>
 
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <TextBlock
                Text="Имя пользователя:"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Margin="0,0,0,5"
                Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBox
                BorderBrush="Gray"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Background="White"
                x:Name="UsernameTextBox"
                Watermark="Введите имя"
                Foreground="Black"/>
        </StackPanel>
 
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <TextBlock
                Text="Электронная почта:"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Margin="0,0,0,5"
                Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBox
                BorderBrush="Gray"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Background="White"
                x:Name="EmailTextBox"
                Watermark="Введите email"
                Foreground="Black">
 
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
 
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <TextBlock
                Text="Пароль:"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Margin="0,0,0,5"
                Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBox
                
                x:Name="PasswordTextBox"
                BorderBrush="Gray"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Background="White"
                Watermark="Введите пароль"
                PasswordChar="*"
                Foreground="Black">
                <TextBox.Styles>
                    
                    <!-- Прямое переопределение состояния focus -->
                    <Style Selector="TextBox:focus">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                    </Style>
 
                </TextBox.Styles>
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
 
        <Button
            Content="Зарегистрироваться"
            Height="40"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Click="RegisterButton_Click"
            Background="#9421db"
            Foreground="White"/>
    </StackPanel>
 
 
 
</Window>


https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions/11740#discussioncomment-6172628

Тут следует обращаться к стилю используя полный пут к этому элементу. В следующий раз можно смотреть документацию по контролам, там все есть.
    <Style Selector="TextBox:focus">
        <Style Selector="^ /template/ Border#PART_BorderElement">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f9b410"/>
        </Style>
    </Style>

